# Ag Grid with Nest Array of Objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I planning to use AG Grid to display a grid. But one of the uses cases I have is around this data structure:

```
{
  "component": "Component Name",
  "model": "Model Name",
  "rules":[
    {
      "ruleId": 1,
      "precondition": true,
      "value": 150
    },
    {
      "ruleId":2,
      "precondition":false,
      "value": 100
    },
    {
      "ruleId":3,
      "precondition":false,
      "value":75
    }
  ]
}
```

I am having a hard time to display the rules as a nested row of component. So far I was able to create the grid if the rules was a single nested object, but my logic breaks when it needs to handle the array object.

I am using the below code to specify the definition of the column:

```
   get gridOptions(): GridOptions {
        return {
          ...this.options,

          defaultColDef: this.defaultColumnDefs,
          columnDefs: this.columnDefs,

          enableCharts: false,

          treeData: true,
          getDataPath: this.dataPath
        };
      }

    get columnDefs(): Array<{children?: Array<_ColDef>; skipKey?: boolean;}> {
        return [
          {
            headerName: 'Component',
            children: this.columnDefs_component
          }
        ];
      }

      get columnDefs_component(): Array<{children?: Array<_ColDef>; skipKey?: boolean;}> {
        return [
          {
            headerName: 'Component',
            field: 'componentName'
          },
          {
            headerName: 'Model',
            field: 'model'
          },
          {
            headerName: 'Rules',
            children: this.columnDefs_rules
          }
        ];
      }

  get columnDefs_rules(): Array<{children?: Array<_ColDef>; skipKey?: boolean;}> {
    return [
      {
        headerName: 'Id',
        field: 'rules.ruleId',
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Limit Value',
        field: 'rules.value'
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Precondition',
        field: 'rules.precondition'
      }
    ];
  }
```

With the above, nothing will display on the cells related to the nested rules object array. I was able to use `valueGetter` and setting a function to return the object array, but it will display a list of `object Object` instead of the values of the rules object.

The thing I am missing is how to tell Ag-Grid that the Rule Column is an array of Rule Objects within the Rule node.

Can someone point me some directions on how to achieve that?

NOTE: I can display a single record by setting the field to `'rules.0.field'` but that will only display the first value of the array, and not the others...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'rules.field' not 'rules.0.field'.

I solved my problem like this:

```
columnDefs.value = [
        {
            field: 'p.title',
            headerName: getColumnLocalizedName('title')
        },
        {
            field: 'p.brand',
            headerName: getColumnLocalizedName('brand')
        }
    ]
```